# Ordering results differently in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has 3 columns. (day, month and year)

This statement gives results in chronological order.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE = 'condition' ORDER BY year, month, day
```

How can I get it in the inverse order?

Comment: _Why_ do you has three separate fields, and don’t use the DATE data type?

Answer (score 4):

You need to invert your sort order in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE = 'condition' ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC
```

Having separate columns for year, month, and day is counter-productive, though, as all of these could be represented in a singular `DATE` type column. This can be indexed and is much faster in practice:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY date_column DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE = 'condition'
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ASC` or `DESC` keywords.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table WHERE = 'condition'
ORDER BY year DESC,
         month DESC,
         day DESC
```

Comment: I'm going to down-vote this for linking to the poison that is [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: It's not because it's w3schools, it's a priori rubbish... I agree w3schools is not affiliated with w3c, but that doesn't make the content less valuable.

Comment: I'll upvote you for giving a correct answer. Judge a man not by the quality of his links. If you don't like the resource linked, just edit the answer to link to a better resource.

Comment: The last thing the internet needs is another link to that site, so I'm just casting my protest vote here. I'm not going to go renegade and start editing people's answers without their consent though.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour at StackOverflow, no biggie. Let's create great content that people can use.